# PXE Booting: Default boot file name?

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, bootp, boot

When implementing PXE booting, is it necessary to specify a specific boot file in the DHCP options, or can you have a default boot file and so not specify that option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PXELINUX server it is recommended to use "filename" option even if it is default boot file. Without specifying it some of the clients might not boot.

This is a good reference for implementing PXE Boot.

[PXELINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX)